# call swift optional protocol method in super

Tags: cocoa, swift

I'd like to make an NSView subclass that handles drag and drop by redirecting it to its view controller. So I have to override NSDraggingDestination protocol methods in my NSView subclass. There I'd like to check if method is supported by view controller implementation and call it, or if not supported to call base class implementation. The first part seems easy by optional chaining, but how do I check if method implemented in super class? For example, this is what I came up for draggingEnded method. It gives a runtime crash inside if block, if the view controller does not implement draggingEnded method.

```
class ControllerChainedView: NSView {

    @IBOutlet weak var chainedController: NSViewController!

    override func draggingEnded(sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
        let destination = chainedController as! NSDraggingDestination
        if !(destination.draggingEnded?(sender) != nil) {
           super.draggingEnded(sender);
       }
    }
}
```

Changing the line inside if to super.draggingEnded?(sender); gives a compiler error. (Operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is '(NSDraggingInfo?) -> Void')

There is no problem with say similar draggingEntered method as it seems to be implemented in NSView.
So the question is how to detect if one can call method in super or not?

Answer (score 0):

If your `super` is based on `NSObject`, you can still use `respondsToSelector:` in this way:

```
if super.respondsToSelector("draggingEnded:") {
  super.draggingEnded(sender)
}
```

**UPDATE - based on 1st Alex comment**

Depends. Generally no, you can't do this with optional chaining without calling it.

But what you can do is to check if function was or wasn't called. But again, in specific cases only. Must be `@objc` protocol, must be based on `NSObject` and return value of optional function must not be Optional.

Check following examples.

```
@objc protocol Opt {
  optional func implemented() -> Void
  optional func notImplemented() -> Void
}

class Object: NSObject, Opt {
  func implemented() {}
}

let o = Object() as Opt
let implementedCalled = o.implemented?() != nil // == true
let notImplementedCalled = o.notImplemented?() != nil // == false
```

In this particular case, `implementedCalled` is set to `true`. In other words, you can at least check if method was called or not. It's because of optional chaining and because `o.implemented` return type is `Void`, `o.implemented?()` returns `Void?`.

You can also do something like this ...

```
if o.implemented != nil {
  // Function is implemented AND implemented WAS CALLED
} else {
  // Function is not implemented
}
```

... but don't forget that it's not check if function is implemented, it's - if function is implemented, call it and return `.Some(Void)` or `.None` if it's not implemented.

In your particular case, you can do this:

```
override func draggingEnded(sender: NSDraggingInfo?) {
  let destination = chainedController as! NSDraggingDestination
  if destination.draggingEnded?(sender) == nil {
    // .None returned - method not implemented in destination

    // draggingEnded is called in super only if it's implemented
    // ignore result of type Void?
    super.draggingEnded?(sender)
  }
}
```

If return type of optional function is not `Void`, but for example `String`, it behaves in the same way.

```
@objc protocol Opt {
  optional func name() -> String
}

class Object: NSObject, Opt {
  func name() -> String { return "Object" }
}

let o = Object() as Opt
let n: String? = o.name?() // n contains "Object"
```

If `name` is not implemented, `n` will contain `None`.

So far, so good. We can check if function was called for `Void` and for `String` (or any other type).

But what if return type is Optional? `String?` for example.

```
@objc protocol Opt {
  optional func name() -> String?
}

class Object: NSObject, Opt {
  func name() -> String? { return nil }
}

class Object2: NSObject, Opt {
}

let o = Object() as Opt
let n = o.name?()

let o2 = Object2() as Opt
let n2 = o2.name?()
```

`Object` implements `name`, but it returns `nil` and `Object2` does not implement `name` at all. But both `n` and `n2` contain `nil`. In other words, if return type is Optional, we can't check if function is or isn't implemented.

As you can see, it's tricky. Sometimes it suits your needs, sometimes not. If you are sure that your object is based on `NSObject`, stick with `.respondsToSelector` to be safe. You can then ignore all these conditions and cases.

If your goal is to just call function if it's implemented and you don't care if it is really implemented or not, if you're not interested in result, you can do it with `?`.

Comment: Is it possible to check with swift optionals? It seems redundant to use both  NSObject specifics and swift's.

Comment: @AlexanderB I just update my answer with more details. It's not redundant, it's different nature of Objective-C and Swift and cooperation between these two languages.

Comment: Trying  super.draggingEnded?(sender) was the first thing I tried, see at the end of the question. It does not compile ( Operand of postfix '?' should have optional type; type is '(NSDraggingInfo?) -> Void'). Trying cast let superDestination = super as NSDraggingDestination does not compile either.

Comment: It is new project created with Xcode 6.3, but I'm do not know how to check  the swift version.

Comment: Swift 1.2 was released along with Xcode 6.3. My example runs perfectly in playground in this version. Will check it in Mac app with NSView to see what's the problem.

Comment: tried this:             
if super.respondsToSelector("draggingEnded:") {
     super.draggingEnded(sender);
}
Gives the same run-time error "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Answer (score 0):

Since the optional syntax `?` is not working for `super` you'll have to check explicitly whether the superclass implements the method.

```
if NSView.instancesRespondToSelector("draggingEnded:") {
    super.draggingEnded(sender)
}
```